# Interpreter failure in executing a binary on armv7l architecture

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

I have a problem executing a binary file in armv7l architecture. I cross-compile my program *hello.cpp* on my PC Linux Ubuntu 18.04

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ hello.cpp -o hello
```

Then I secure copy it to my device and try to run it but I receive an error saying:

```
-sh: ./hello: not found
```

However when I include *-static* into my cross-compilation

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ hello.cpp -o hello -static
```

The program runs normally.

What could cause a problem when executing the file in Linux APSA30F59 4.14.36 armv7l without *-static* flag?

What does it really mean to include *-static* while compiling?

Comment: By including the `-static` flag, you are instructing the toolchain to include _all_ code required to execute the application... including libc.

Comment: Using `/lib/ld-linux.so` on pc and device i get: `bash: /lib/ld-linux.so: No such file or directory`. Same with `/lib/ld.so`. While with `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on normal g++ compiled file on my pc i get: `./hello: error while loading shared libraries: ./hello: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

Comment: Writing `/lib/ld*.so* --list ./hello` or `/lib/ld*.so* --list hello` or just `/lib/ld*.so*` i get `loader cannot load itself`

Answer (score 0):

Upon compilation, the ubuntu created a wrong linker for the interpreter on a device. By running the command

```
patchelf --print-interpreter hello
```

the output is wrong for the library in a device.

```
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

I changed it to the right one by

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3 hello
```

And the program ran successfully.

The alternative solution is to make a soft link from the program interpreter to the right interpreter on the device.

```
ln /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ld-linux.so.3
```

I guess it has something to do with the compiler version mismatch. Please correct me if I'm wrong.